# How should I type elementary OS? With a lowercase e or an uppercase E?

Tags: design, elementary-project

Should I type `elementary OS` or `Elementary OS`?

What's the difference between `elementary` and `elementary OS`?

Should I call the system `eOS`?

Comment: here is the related meta post http://meta.elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/5/lets-enforce-branding-guidelines-in-edits

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`elementary` is the name used for the entire project (operating system and everything else related to it). `elementary OS` is just the name of the operating system, not the entire project.

elementary's team prefers typing its name with a lowercase `e` for consistency. So, you should always type `elementary` instead of `Elementary` (even if it's in the beginning of the sentence).

elementary's team prefers that you do not refer to `elementary OS` as `eOS` because that kind of mimics Apple's `iThings`, KDE's `KThis` and GNOME's `GThat` trends, which they're trying to avoid.

Source: [The Importance of Our Brand](http://blog.elementary.io/post/107640994166/the-importance-of-our-brand) (Internal Branding Guidelines section)

Further reading: [Let's enforce branding guidelines in edits](https://elementaryos.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5/lets-enforce-branding-guidelines-in-edits) (meta post)

Comment: inconsistently, when posting on elementary g+ a question, eOS logo appears. [Like so.](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/u8HpcXNJonI1qLFvdRncIvUms7ehaTzzDcmao5F1xZO38U2tpA-uigwihXXLuPxDRNaC_JJO4ljDNdm-267tCBY2IfpYYNrBkoafrbUfCP3qJsJ1C14RSlM0SC8gR7ukARLWP9qm=w120-h120)

Comment: @cipricus I remember reading somewhere in Meta that elementary's team has no control over that and that they would love to change that, but they can't do that in the current (public beta) stage of the StackExchange site.