# Is this panel area a system tray?

Tags: release-freya, icons, wingpanel

Before being edited [this answer](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/4227/170) was suggesting that elementary OS does not have a system tray.

I would like to know more about this. What is the difference between this and what I see in other desktops like Xfce etc and why some apps don't show an icon here when they should, while others do.

[image]

Comment: please comment when down-voting and i'll try fix what's wrong

Comment: Don't call elementary OS eOS. I have done the changes for you but take a look @ http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/850/how-should-i-type-elementary-os-with-a-lowercase-e-or-an-uppercase-e

Comment: I have renamed eOS to elementary OS in all the posts I could (some contain eOS in `uname` output)

Comment: @SuiciDoga - Why is this important? are there some rights involved? I personally would like to see eOS used for elementary, like one says MS for Microsoft, Mint or LM for Linux Mint etc

Comment: Did you read the link?

Comment: Marking this as a duplicate since this information is now contained in the other post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That *is* a System Tray, and the answer you link to is somewhat contradictory.

> elementary OS does not have a system tray
>   ...
>   Currently (in 0.3 Freya), only the Ayatana Indicator API is respected.

Ayatana Indicators do exist in a system tray in Freya, however they will not in Loki.

Comment: I suggest you comment the linked answer and argue the OP to clarify.

Comment: I have appended an edit for clarification.

Comment: This answer is not really accurate. System Tray is the actual user-facing name of the GtkStatusIcon API. The Ayatana Indicator API is never referred to as a "system tray". They are pretty different APIs in terms of the things they allow.