# Is it correct/acceptable to use 'eOS' as an acronym for elementary OS?

Tags: design, elementary-project

It's ["elementary" and not "Elementary"](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/851/170).

But what about eOS?

[image]

[Here](https://elementaryos.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5/170):

> "eos" is the name of a line of beauty products or Canon cameras. We
>   don't consider this an acceptable way to refer to elementary OS. This
>   is especially important in not encouraging 3rd parties to make brands
>   such as "eRadio" or "eCleaner"

[Here](http://blog.elementary.io/post/107640994166/the-importance-of-our-brand):

> The word “elementary” should be used when referring to the overarching
>   project. “elementary OS” is a product of elementary. The “e” should
>   always be written in lowercase. Don’t use “eOS” as an abbreviation for
>   elementary OS; it sounds a lot like a certain fruity operating system
>   and reminds us of the “KThis” and “GThat” trend.

Why is it necessary to avoid the K/KDE, G/Gnome, i/Intel trend?

Comment: I believe that I have already answered this question in: [How should I type elementary OS? With a lowercase e or an uppercase E?](http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/850/how-should-i-type-elementary-os-with-a-lowercase-e-or-an-uppercase-e)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No , it is not

There must be lots of E things like eRadio , eSoft , eFM , eSettings and eLaptop . elementary want to have the elementary brand and not the E brand (if they did want to they would call their apps things like eDesktop (instead of pantheon) and ePhotos).

It is not acceptable to use it as an achronim for elementary OS since it could mean something else and elementary wants the elementary brand.

They also must not be wanting to copy KDE's K things , Intel's i things and GNOME's G things

Comment: it's odd that eOS logo appears in some contexts, like for example when I add an elementaryos.stackexchange link into g+elementary:https://plus.google.com/+CipricusCipriq/posts/YhFdd9VbwYG

Comment: @cipricus yeah, it's unfortunately the logo that StackExchange gave us. I'm unsure how to change it, but it's absolutely not something we designed or endorsed.